# How to get elements of a collection that are not in another collection?

Tags: python

I am a Java programmer, but there is a task, where the better way to resolve it is to use (the more effective and suitable for the server) python, which is not familiar to me.

What about task? I have file, which contains sorted ids (~5 mln ids) in such format:

```
00000011-1f0e-4d89-b658-af53b36c882e
0000008a-5816-4324-82f6-9242a8867094
000000be-d08c-41b9-97f3-594d2660dfb5
000000f2-ea63-48c0-98f6-1dbb25f0249e
0000014d-f6b0-4b3e-b767-14cd2495fd81
00000155-ec3b-4d1a-a3ae-28e95cfc79c7
00000231-65f9-424a-bf03-1d3cbefc6c40
00000281-cb21-4d3c-ba13-874161962567
000002be-6e9d-455d-aa16-49e2ac242868
00000375-4d9a-4dd6-8e0c-38e5c2134a3c
00000383-fc20-4154-921c-c187bb3f6628
000003fc-7a06-4525-a12a-df64732324e5
00000420-af64-4015-9bc4-6b9e18b86183
00000476-1bf9-4608-8979-d60ecd5b368b
...
```

Also I have another file, which contains ~60 mln sorted ids. The format is the same.

I need to read all ids from the first file to variable for example `l1` and read all ids from the second file to variable for example `l2`. After that I want to find all elements of the `l1`, which are absent in `l2` and write them to the third file. The first files are many, that is why I must repeat these actions from time to time.

Tell me, please, what is the best way to choose for solving this problem, which object types to use for `l1` and `l2` (the lists of ids are sorted) and what will the python script look like all in all?

Comment: You can use sets and their functions/methods, such as intersections. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Read each into a `set` then use `set.difference`.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you! Do I correctly understand that it is not necessary to sort the ids in file when we use the set?

Comment: @Passerby I need to get mismatched elements only from the first set `l1`. Does `set.difference` help me? I think, that the result will include mismatched elements from both l1 and l2

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set You are describing `set.symmetric_difference`

Comment: Elements (or the files) do indeed not have to be sorted (it may happen under the hood of the set implementation in Python, but that shouldn't really consider you).

Comment: Your only challenge may be that 5 million items will take some time. Then again, I expect the set implementation to be well optimised, even for large set sizes. Also, from your question, it appears there could be quite some duplicates in the large file, which would shrink the final set considerably.

Comment: @9769953 Yeah! I understood you and absolutely agree with you. Thank you for the tip to use the set. You helped me a lot

Comment: @Passerby Oh, sorry! I just figured out the difference between `set.difference` and `set.symmetric_difference` and tested it with an example. You are really right! Now I understand you. You helped me a lot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element in first set, not in second set:

```py
s1=set([1,2,3,4,5])
s2=set([3,4,5,6,7])
s3=s1-s2
print(s3)
```

For this file merge scenario, you can google for a better algorithm to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your example works well. But may be usage of `set.difference` is more effective in case of millions ids

Comment: Great, maybe your right.